# Gatsby SCSS Module not compiling

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

Running Gatsby version 3.0.1, with sass 1.32.8. I've just started playing about with a few things and I've come into a weird problem that I cannot work out.

`./gatsby-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        implementation: require("sass"),
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

`./src/pages/index.js`

```
import React from "react"
import homeStyles from '../styles/scss/index.module.scss'

export default function Home() {
  return <div className={homeStyles.testElement}>Hello world!</div>
}
```

`./styles/scss/index.module.scss`

```
.testElement {
  font-size: 72px;
}
```

The error I get is `Attempted import error: '../styles/scss/index.module.scss' does not contain a default export (imported as 'homeStyles').`

If I try with `import * as homeStyles from '../styles/scss/index/module.scss` the error is: `Attempted import error: 'testElement' is not exported from '../styles/scss/index.module.scss' (imported as 'homeStyles').`

Without knowing precisely how the plugin works, I cannot see any issues that would be causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like:

```
module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    },
  ],
}
```

You don't need to add extra implementations to work with CSS modules, so you can omit them.

In addition, according to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30037) the solution is to downgrade the plugin to `v4`.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error. I tried removing the plugin and reinstalling but that had no effect.

Comment: Try downgrading to Gatsby v2. The implementation of the v3 depends on the plugin's code so until they update it you may face some caveats or issues

Comment: Turns out it was somewhat of an edge case. The newest version they release (4.0.1) which happens to have been released within the last 24hrs has a bug. Downgrading to 4.0.0 for the time being works. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30037

Comment: Thanks for the insights! I've updated the answer with the workaround. Have you finally fixed it downgrading the dependency?

Comment: Downgrading fixes it for the time being!

Answer (score 2):

Try to import * as homeStyles and you should be golden:

```
import React from "react"
import * as homeStyles from '../styles/scss/index.module.scss'

export default function Home() {
  return <div className={homeStyles.testElement}>Hello world!</div>
}
```